# Dynamically adding directive to element in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive called "resizable" that adds functionality to an element to make it resizable.

I want to conditionally apply this directive to an element from a controller.

When I add this directive at run-time using `attr`, the attribute for the "resizable" directive is added, but the directive doesn't execute.

Here's an illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3995/

What I'm expecting is that when `$('span').attr('resizable', '');` is called, the class `funky` should be added to the `span`. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `$compile` directive to notify angular of the changes. Basically the logic goes like this: "I've changed something within my element that you should be concerned about. Please compile the DOM against my scope":

```
function Controller($scope, $compile) {
    // Apply resizable directive to span
    var span = $('span');
    span.attr('resizable', '');

    $compile(span)($scope);
}
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

**NOTE:** You SHOULD NOT use jQuery natively within a controller (... or anywhere really). It may select `span` tags outside of your element of interest. You SHOULD try writing a directive to wrap the logic that applies your resizable directive.